# Eclipse plug-in to edit faces-config.xml file

Tags: eclipse, jsf, eclipse-plugin, jsf-1.2

I work in [XPages](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xpages/info) (which is built on JSF) for which we use Domino Designer which is built on Eclipse platform (3.4.2). When we edit `faces-config.xml` file it shows in XML editor.

I am looking for a plugin which can enable editing of `faces-config.xml` file like the one shown in below image. I got this image from [here](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2009/11/25/using-eclipse-faces-config-visual-editor/).

[image: faces-config.xml editor]

I just want the plugin for editor for `faces-config.xml`. While searching I found a lot of references to Web Tools Platform. I checked [this page of Web Tools Platform](http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/downloads/drops/R3.4.2/R-3.4.2-20130208151217/) but couldn't find any references to JSF.

Is there any standalone editor for `faces-config.xml` file?

Answer (score 0):

No,

but you can use the JBoss Developer Studio. There are more editors like VPE.

Checkout some tutorials on Youtube: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OMtcjgTyP-g

[image: This for example:]

Comment: Actually I require for Eclipse only as we work on Domino Designer which is built on Eclipse.

Comment: try to install the jboss tools into domino designer.

Comment: I am bit late on replying, sorry! But I am facing some issues while installing JBoss tools in Domino Designer. May be because Eclipse has been modified that's why. Any other alternatives?